# Windows Javascript application sequence images error

Tags: javascript, .net, html, winjs, windows

I am trying to display images sequentially in Windows Application Js App. The script is as follows. This is working in notepad but it's not working in ".net". I added separate file "scrolling.js"  to home folder and the below code is in it. Error is pointing towards rotator.src . Am I missing anything?

```
 <body>
        <!-- The content that will be loaded and displayed. -->
        <div class="fragment homepage">
            <header aria-label="Header content" role="banner">
                <button class="win-backbutton" aria-label="Back" disabled type="button"></button>
                <h1 class="titlearea win-type-ellipsis">
                    <span class="pagetitle">Welcome to AppTweenMax!</span>
                </h1>
            </header>
            <section aria-label="Main content" role="main">
                <div id="demo">Content goes here.</div>
                <img src="imagesroll/1.png" alt="rotating image" width="640" height="960" id="rotator">
                          </section>     


        </div>    
      <script type="text/javascript">
            (function () {
                var rotator = document.getElementById('rotator');  // change to match image ID
                var imageDir = 'imagesroll/';                          // change to match images folder
                var delayInSeconds = 2;                            // set number of seconds delay
                // list image names
                var images = ['2.png', '3.png', '4.png', '5.png', '6.png', '7.png'];

                // don't change below this line
                var num = 0;
                var changeImage = function () {
                    var len = images.length;
                    var src = imageDir + images[num++];       
                    document.getElementById('rotator').src = "" + src;
                    rotator.src = src;
                    if (num == len) {
                        num = 0;
                    }
                };
                setInterval(changeImage, delayInSeconds * 1000);
            })();
    </script>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to rotate a static set of images, you need to add them to the windows store app project. Use `add existing items`->`add as link` to add the images. This assumes all images are in a folder `<myprojectdir>\images`. Ensure that `right click`->`properties`->`package action` is set as 'content'. This will ensure that images are packaged as part of the app package.

then, use image path like `/images/1.png` assuming you have the images under folder 'images' in the project. you can also use absolute path of kind `ms-appx:///images/1.png`

this code works:

```
var rotator = document.getElementById('rotator');  // change to match image ID
var imageDir = 'images/';                          // change to match images folder
var delayInSeconds = 2;                            // set number of seconds delay
// list image names
var images = ['2.png', '3.png', '4.png', '5.png', '6.png', '7.png'];

var num = 0;
var changeImage = function ()
{
    var len = images.length;
    var src = 'ms-appx:///' + imageDir + images[num++];
    rotator.src = src;
    if (num == len)
    {
        num = 0;
    }
};
setInterval(changeImage, delayInSeconds * 1000);
```

Comment: share your html and js file contents

Comment: image path should start with `/` which is missing. That is `/imagesroll`. secondly, the script code needs to be in the ready event handler of the page in the .js file. refer the sample pages added when you created a new project with say grid template.

Comment: If I start with /imagesroll, it is not displaying atleast the "1.png". As it is displaying only the "1.png" until now. I tried js part in placing new javascript file also but it's not working. If I check the html file from the app folder outside '.net' - it is working in browser.

Answer (score 0):

Bro you have to erase this line --> rotator.src = src;
and your code works!